# Is there a cipher or encoding that turns letters/words into numbers? (Excluding ASCII & alphabet)

Tags: encryption

I'd like a word to be turned into a number in a way that distinguishes between lowercase/uppercase letters (eg R != r) Thanks.

Comment: Cipher and encoding are totally different things. Write as a byte convert it to big integer..

Comment: Why don't you want to use ASCII or alphabet??

Comment: It doesn't matter why I don't want to use alphabet *groan* NO MORE ALPHABET PLEASE

Comment: It would help if you could give a reason or at least some restrictions because there are a lot of ways to convert words to numbers, and it is hard to come up with a solution when you eliminate the two most obvious answers. For example, would numbering the words in a dictionary be closer to what you want? (noting that most dictionaries don't distinguish upper/lower case, so wouldn't be a solution in itself)

Comment: @sneaky_snayke well we need some more info on the restrictions, because without ASCII or alphabet, it can get a bit tricky... does output size matter?? Does it have to be reversible?? What is the end use going to be??

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with alphabet?

Suppose you have uppercase first and lowercase, then you code
$$
A = 0, B = 1, \ldots, Z = 25, a = 26, \ldots, z = 51.
$$

**Example of encoding**

Take a word like `Hello`. It can be written as
$$
(7, 30, 37, 37, 40).
$$

Finally, to make a single integer out of this list of numbers:
$$
\mathbf 7 + \mathbf{30} \times 52 + \mathbf{37} \times 52^2 + \mathbf{37} \times 52^3 + \mathbf{40} \times 52^4 = 297768751.
$$
And you have the encoding of `Hello`.

**Example of decoding**

Take the number `297768751`. The decoding consists in finding this number in base 52:

- Compute $297768751 \bmod 52 = 7$, and $7$ is $H$;
- Compute $C = (297768751-7)/52$ which is an integer;
- Compute $C \bmod 52 = 30$, and $30$ is $e$;
- etc.

This is just an example. You can use any alphabet you want, bigger or smaller. And remember, as @kelalaka said, this is not a cipher, just an encoding.

Comment: I don't want alphabet )-:<

Comment: You have been asked multiple times about the restrictions and you didn't answer, @sneaky_snayke. Indicate what kind of numbering scheme *is* acceptable, or you may be presented with an alphabet (or two, for uppercase/lowercase) in reverse.

Comment: Everything is acceptable that is not listed as not acceptable. EZ